Is the square of a separable state again separable?
Famously, a bipartite quantum state $\rho\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}\otimes\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ is defined to be separable if and only if
$$
\rho\in{\rm conv}\{ \omega\otimes\sigma : \omega\in\mathbb C^{n\times n},\sigma\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}\text{ density matrices} \}\,,
$$
i.e., if and only if $\rho=\sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_j\omega_j\otimes\sigma_j$ with states $\omega_j,\sigma_j$, and $\lambda_j\geq 0$, $\sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_j=1$.
This notion of separability can be generalized to positive semi-definite matrices $A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}\otimes\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ by saying that $A$ is separable if there exist positive semi-definite matrices $B_1,\ldots,B_k\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ and $C_1,\ldots,C_k\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ such that
$$
A=\sum_{j=1}^k B_j\otimes C_j\,.
$$
One interesting question is which classes of maps preserve this separability structure. Such separability-preserving maps include: entanglement-breaking channels, separable operations (e.g., LOCC operations), or the partial transpose.
Going one step further, but one could relax this notion to include non-linear operations, as well, eg., squaring the density matrix, i.e., applying the map $A \mapsto A^2$. This—obviously non-linear—map is natural to consider as it is positive and unital. This raises the question:

If $\rho$ is separable, is $\rho^2$ necessarily separable?

Based on some easy observations, this claim holds in specific cases:

The square of a product state is trivially still a product state; in particular, the claim holds for all pure states $\rho$ (i.e., all extreme points of the separable states).
If $\rho$ is diagonal in a product basis, then $\rho^2$ is also diagonal and hence separable.

However, does squaring preserve separability in general?

(This is a Q&A style question meant as a contribution to the list of counterexamples in quantum information)

This sounds like a rather contrived question. Why would one wonder about that?

@NorbertSchuch At some point I had wondered whether the set of separable states is a semigroup or enjoys some other suitable product invariance structure, my motivation being that there are powerful tools in Lie semigroup theory which allow to analyze convex, compact semigroups (such as, e.g., channels). However, not only do the separable states not form a semigroup (trivially, because the positive semi-definite matrices don't), but even the simplest multiplicative operation $X\mapsto X^2$ does not leave this set invariant. That's the origin of this question & counterexample.

I see. On the other hand, such semigroups would have to be very special (e.g. one-parameter), since in general the product of two density matrices is not even hermitian. (In some sense, this is also what underlies the counterexample.)

It turns out that just because $\rho$ is separable, $\rho^2$ need not be separable. For a counterexample, consider
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2} ( |00\rangle \langle 00|\,+ \,|\!+\!+\rangle \langle+\! +\!|),
$$
where $|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1, 1)^\top$. In matrix form, this state is given by
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{8} \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
and it is separable by construction (or by PPT). Now consider its square
$$
\rho^2 = \frac{1}{16} \begin{pmatrix} 7 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
and notice that the partial transpose of $\rho^2$ features a negative block
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
(up to a global factor) which has a negative determinant. Hence $\rho^2$ is entangled due to PPT.

Let me give an alternative answer, with three goals:  First, to show that this behavior (i.e. that for a separable $\rho$, $\rho^2$ is entangled) is very likely (and if one also asks for higher powers, generic -- that is, any random separable state will have entangled powers);
second, that this also happens in the multi-partite setting; and third, to give a physics-based intuition why this is the case.
Let me start with the physics-based intuition, as this is what led me here: We can think of $\rho$ as the Gibbs state of some Hamiltonian, $\rho=\exp[-\beta H]$.$^1$ Then, $\rho^2$ is the Gibbs state at $\beta'=2\beta$, or half the temperature.
This is saying that when we compare $\rho^2$ and $\rho$, we compare the entanglement of a state at some temperature ($\rho^2$) and at twice the temperature ($\rho$). Now, if we go to very high temperature, the state is getting closer and closer (at an exponential rate) to a maximally mixed state. On the other hand, it is also well known that if a state is sufficiently close to a maximally mixed state, it is separable.
We can use this to "reverse engineer" examples:

Start from an entangled state $\sigma$, and take its eigenvalue decomposition. Then, replace any eigenvalue $\lambda$ by $\lambda^{1/n}$. For a sufficiently large $n$, the resulting state $\rho$ will become separable (as it approaches the maximally mixed state); conversely, $\rho$ then forms an example for which $\rho^n$ is separable. (From there, we can also find a pair of states $\tau$ where $\tau$ is separable while $\tau^2$ is entangled, since the transition must happen at some power $n$).
(Genericness:) Take an arbitrary separable state $\rho$, with the only constraint that its largest eigenvalue is unique, and the corresponding eigenvector is entangled.$^2$  Then, for increasing $n$, $\rho^n$ approaches the projector onto that largest eigenvector, and thus, for large enough $n$, $\rho^n$ will be entangled.

Finally, the very same arguments also apply in the multipartite setting, since  a state which is close enough to the identity is also separable in a multipartite sense.

$^1$ There's some caveats if $\rho$ does not have full rank, but this is a subclass of measure zero. Indeed, two-qubit states with Bell rank two form a class of counterexamples, as they are all entangled independent of the weight (unless both weights are equal).
$^2$ Any random separable $\rho$ will have this property. One way to get a subclass of random separable states $\rho$ (with that property) is to start with a random $\rho$ and mix it with the maximally mixed state until it becomes separable.
